# Save DB with php function stripslashes

Tags: php, html, database, sql-update

I have one problem with save $p on database.If I save $_POST["content"] unmodified it works.
But if I modify with stripslashes it is not work.I do not understand the reason.

```
$_POST["content"] is text from function innerHTML
mysql_connect("XX","XX","XX");
mysql_select_db("XX");
$p=stripslashes($_POST["content"]);
mysql_query("UPDATE TEXTO SET VALOR='.$p.' WHERE id=2");
```

Comment: *Obligatory [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) remark...*  PDO, use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't want to strip slashes before updating a database, you'd actually want to do the opposite. I would recommend

```
$p=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["content"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is where the error is:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE TEXTO SET VALOR='.$p.' WHERE id=2");
```

You don't need the periods around `$p`. You can do this as:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE TEXTO SET VALOR='$p' WHERE id=2");
```

Or:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE TEXTO SET VALOR='".$p."' WHERE id=2");
```

The double quotes around the string will interpolate variables when it's evaluated.

**However**

You should really look at moving away from using `mysql_*` functions, as they're being deprecated; either `PDO` or `mysqli_*` will let you write code that is more secure, too.